# How to get inner element using parent object without using parent and children jquery function

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am having

```
<div id=test>
<div class="a"> </div>
<div class="b"> </div>
<div class="c"> </div>
</div>
```

i have to get third div i.e class name with c using parent obj.

For eg if i do `$("#test .c")` i am getting element.

But i am unable to get element using parent element as object 
for eg

```
var obj = $("#test");
$(obj+".c")
```

is not giving me output. 
It is giving me error "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]"

Please let me know how it is possible.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search for the element with class `c` within the context of the jQuery Object:

```
var obj = $("#test");
$(".c", obj);
```

Alternatively you could use:

```
obj.find(".c");
```

Or:

```
$(obj.selector+" .c");
```

Comment: This solution with the context seems most in line with the OP seems to want.

Comment: Thats pretty smart, does it only search the DOM of the object then?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
obj.find('.c');
```

More info on [find in the jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you combine an object and class selector.

Try

```
var obj = $("#test");
var objID = obj.attr('id');
$(objID+".c")
```

Else you could do it with the object like

```
var obj = $("#test");
$(obj).children('.c')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var objC = $("#test .c");
```

would select all c's inside test's